# How to open en close menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Building my first website and cant open en close the menu using javascript ( first time javascript so be gentle ). This is my code in the following order. HTML/CSS/Java.I know that i have to point to id instead of class in CSS, i thought i did it right but can't get it working`.

So this is my HTML code i use visual studio code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project R-K</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="logo" herf=#> R&K<span>Productions</span></a>
            
        <img id="mobile-open" class="mobile-menu" src="images/icons8-menu.svg" alt="open navigation">
        
        
        <nav>
            <img id="mobile-close" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/icons8-delete.svg" alt="Close navigation">
             
            <ul class="primary-nav">  
                  <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="#">About us</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
              </ul>  

              <ul class="secundary-nav">  
                <li> <a href="#">Buy R&K dollars</a></li>
                <li class= "Make-account"> <a href="#">Make account</a></li>
                
            </ul>  

            </nav>
</div>
</div>

<section class="hero">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
        <p class="subhead">Funny &amp; making you money!</p>
        <h1>A gamer website, by gamers for gamers</h1>
        <div class="hero-cta">
         <a href="#" class="primairy-action">Try for free</a>    
         <a href="#" class="video-action">
                <img src="images/icons8-binoculars.svg" alt="Watch a gamer">Watch a gamer

         </a>    

        </div>
    </section>
    <img src="images/PSImage.jpg" class="hero-image" alt="Ps-image">
    </div>
    <section class="features-section">
<div class="container">
<ul class="feature-list">
    <li>Awesome community</li>
    <li>Maximale adrenaline</li>
    <li>Easy to use</li>
    <li>All possible games</li>
    <img class="oldskool" src="images/Oldskool.jpg" alt="arcade">
</ul>

</div>
</section>


<section class="explanation-in-short">
<div class="container">
We are Richard and Kick and we are gamers since the early stages of our lifes and very dear friends so we have created something that has been missing in the gamer community.
This is a website where you can subscribe and make money playing your favorite game! Try it and find out just how awesome we are!
</div>
</section>

<section class="contact-section">
<div class="container">
<div class="contact-left">
<h2>Contact</h2>

<form action="">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="send-message-cta" value="send message">


</form>


    </div>

</div>

</section>

    
</div>
</section>
    </div>

    
        
    </script>
        </body>
            </html>
```

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;500&display=swap');

```
:root{ 
        --primary-color: rgb(252, 8, 142);

}


body {  
    background: rgb(245, 243, 243);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'poppins';
} 

.navbar {
    background:rgb(245, 243, 243);
    padding: 1em;

    .logo {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: var(--primary-color);    
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

        span {
            color: black;
        }
        
        nav {
        display: none;
        
        }
        
        .container {
                    display: flex;
                    place-content: space-between;
        }
    
        .mobile-menu {
            cursor: crosshair;
            
        }
    
    
    }

    a { 
        color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
    }

    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    section{
        padding: 5em 2em;

    }

    .hero {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .left-col{

        .subhead {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--primary-color);
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.5em;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            margin-top: .2em;
        }

        .primairy-action {
            background: var(--primary-color);
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: .6em 1.3em;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            border-radius: 5em;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: crosshair;
        }

        .video-action {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 1em;

            img{
            margin-right: .5em;
            }
        }

    }

    .hero-image{
        
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: .5em;     
        margin-left: 7em;
    }
    
    .features-section {
        background: rgb(83, 83, 83);
        color: white;
        
    }

    .feature-list {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: .1em;
        display: grid;  

        li {

            font-size: 1.1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            margin-left: 2em;
            position: relative;

            &:before {
                content: '';
                left: -2em;
                position: absolute;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background-image: url('../Images/icons8-checked.svg');
                background-size: contain;
                margin-right: .5em;
            }
        }
    }

    .oldskool{
        display: none;
    }

    .explanation-in-short{
        background: var(--primary-color);
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

    h2{
        font-size: 2em;

    }

    label{
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    input, textarea{

        width: 100%;
        padding: .8em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        box-sizing: border-box;


    }

    .send-message-cta {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 5em;
        border-radius: 5em;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: .8em 2em;
        width: unset;
        cursor: crosshair;

    }

nav{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:rgb(83, 83, 83) ;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;


    ul.primary-nav{
        margin-top: 5em;
    }

    li {
        
        a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: .5em;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            text-align: right;
            
            &:hover {

                font-weight: bold;
                color: var(--primary-color)



            }
            
        }
    }
}
  


.mobile-menu-exit {

    float: right;
    margin: .5em;
    cursor: crosshair;

}



 <script>
                    const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-open')
                    nav = document.querySelector('nav')
                    mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit');
            
                    mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => 
                    {nav.classList.add('mobile-open')
                    });
                   </script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. This is not a [mcve]. Please fix the formatting (why is there text in the code block that doesn't belong there?)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Sorry guys, as you can see i am fairly new here and this is my second question tried to describe it as good as possible. so what i want is to be able to open en close by clicking on  the image with id="mobile-open", and i want to close the image by clicking on the img with id="mobile-close". i will delete the code in the code block. Again thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS :focus-within pseudo class. If you want to do it with JS, first of all you should write the true semantic. In your markup, the menu which you want to open should be written equilavent as your button and you can set this menu's opacity to 0, visibility hidden and display none, then you have to listen for click events coming from your buttons, when the click event fires, you should determine which button was clicked then you can select the menu which you want to open, and make it visible. I still advise to use :focus-within.